# SQLite VS. Plain Text (Android/Newbie)

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I am making my first android app, a simple name generator, to familiarise myself with eclipse and android. I have a small background in java programming (Just finished 1st year of college) and just want to keep practicing.

My question is whether I should use a SQLite database or a plain text file to store the name fragments. I am familiar with doing it with plain text but it is cumbersome, and I have found a lot of arguments that suggest I should learn how to use SQLite.

1. At this point in time (just practicing for myself), is there any reason I should choose one over the other?
2. What are the pro's and cons of doing it either way?
3. I'm not particularly familiar with performance and  avoiding memory leaks, etc. Will this design choice have much impact on that?

*EDIT: After a bit more digging, I found this (I don't know how I missed it the first time) which I think is quite useful for anyone in the same situation. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: What is the data which you want to store exactly?

Comment: Just name fragments, like for instance, a human name would consist of a forename, a surname, and perhaps a prefix/conjunction such as 'von' or 'Mc'. I need them to have identifiers so I can call them to construct a new name at random. Using custom delimiters seems heavy handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for the SQLite option.

In almost any case this is the best solution. Even with simple data structures, it gives you more control and the option to expand later on.

As you're learning, this is what you want to learn since nearly every serious app you'll make will need one.

As to answer your questions exactly;

1. You want to learn how to use a Database. Its the preferred way to store data in general. Its efficient, fast and easy  and most importantly easy to expand.
2. I wouldn't know what the pros are for doing it plain text wise. It's a lot of extra hassle and hard to maintain when expanding.
3. Not really. Just follow a proper tutorial.

You can check out http://vogella.de/ which has a great range of basic tutorials with proper examples.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Clear and concise. With so much functionality it is hard to figure out which bits to learn outright and which bits will come with time. Well... i'm off to mess with SQLite. Thanks guys!